# Using scripts on iOS with the Userscripts app never seem to work?

Tags: script, discussion

I'm using the [Userscripts app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/userscripts/id1463298887) for mobile Safari. My phone is an iPhone 13 running **15.6.1 operating system**. I use this app for other scripts. So it does, at least for some things, work as expected.

I have two **StackApps** scripts loaded and active. Yet they never seem to change the appearance or behavior of stackoverflow.com?

I have Userscripts enabled for all websites. Is there something else I must do?

Script status:
Endless Google - public one, works.
Roomba Forcaster - from here, works.
Stackexchange Global Flag Summary - from here - error see image.
Sox - from here, no sign it works.

[image][image]
[image: flag]

Comment: The post needs a bit more details: app used (linked) and OS version, to be specific.  As for the crux of the matter, that can probably only be answered by an iOS user or the developer of the app - from a cursory glance, provided the app works as intended, the userscripts should load and work.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post with details! Hmm, are you saying that some other userscripts work properly? Then it mght be that those two specific ones rely on the functionality not available or buggy on iOS, however, that is not easy to establish for sure.

Comment: Yes I use the Endless Google script to avoid clicking next. It works as expected.

Comment: Updated with script status